# Handling API lags with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loading

I'm pulling from an API that takes like 30 seconds to load in the data. Right now I have a loading widget that displays while the API is fetching data, but I was curious if there is a way to show the previous data while the updated data is fetching?

For example, let's say I'm pulling in total payout. The total payout was $100,500. Then, at the next fetch it's $100,501. Then $100,502. Is there a way I can display the old number while the new number is being fetched (as opposed to displaying a loading widget)?

Here is the code:

```
const { userStats = null } = props;
const [poolStats, setPoolStats] = useState(null);
const loadingPool = poolStats === null;
const loadingUser = userStats === null;
const { hashrate: userHashrate = null } = loadingUser ? {} : userStats;
useEffect(() => {
   async function loadPoolStats() {
       try {
           const response = await fetchPoolStats();
           setPoolStats(response);
        } catch (e) { 
            console.debug(e);
        }
    }
    if (poolStats === null) {
       loadPoolStats();
    }
 }, [poolStats]);
```

Comment: Have you tried not displaying the loading component after the API call? I mean the loading component mounts when you tell it to.

Comment: If I get rid of the loading widget, then the API will fetch but it will just be a blank screen for like 20 seconds and then it will populate

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You should try to create a minimal example but instead of using an API call just use setTimeout. Then post the example here so that we can see.

Comment: here is the code

Comment: const { userStats = null } = props;
  const [poolStats, setPoolStats] = useState(null);
  const loadingPool = poolStats === null;
  const loadingUser = userStats === null;
  const { hashrate: userHashrate = null } = loadingUser ? {} : userStats;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadPoolStats() {
      try {
        const response = await fetchPoolStats();
        setPoolStats(response);
      } catch (e) {
        console.debug(e);
      }
    }
    if (poolStats === null) {
      loadPoolStats();
      
    }
  }, [poolStats]);